# How to add breakpoints to C# or F# like rails-pry, and then use commands to debug?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, debugging, .net-core, f#

I want to debug `dotnet` core and `Asp.net core` projects in terminal, but I did not find that `dotnet` commands provides debug flag.

By the way, I don't want to use Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code C# / F# extensions.

Comment: [Here](https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/command-line-debugging-core-linux/) is a blog entry that may help you out. But I need to ask, why don't you want to use Visual Studio or VS Code? Visual Studio is purpose built to write and debug the .NET family of languages as well as C/C++, and VS Code is a very powerful text editor/ with the right extensions a very powerful IDE

Comment: Thank you. Because this kind of ide is very big, just for debugging, do not want to install such a big thing. I only use vscode as an editor, that is, read and write files. I use the command line to complete other tasks.

Comment: Visual Studio is quite large yes, but VS Code is comparably tiny. The C# extensions are also quite lightweight. I urge you to give them a try, as it will increase your productivity while reducing headaches of having to jump through hoops to solve a simple problem

Comment: [VS for mac doesn't even have a button to open the folder!](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi0q4qzqr3pAhWK-mEKHdaaBkQQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopercommunity.visualstudio.com%2Fcontent%2Fproblem%2F459820%2Fcant-open-folder-in-vs2019.html&usg=AOvVaw3Vl1DTTgaVCU4UQbMbxwJ0)

Comment: You shouldn't open folders in Visual Studio, rather open individual projects (.csproj file) or entire solutions (.sln file). What you see in the solution explorer of Visual Studio isn't necessarily what's on disk.

Comment: The experience of VS is really bad. If my program runs inside the container, it will be more troublesome. I think I can give up Dotnet.

Comment: I originally planned to use Dotnet in order to use Azure. Now I find that Go and Python and C can use all services of Azure. This gives me more reasons not to use Dotnet.